# Is an early escape normal in encounter 1C?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

In First Scenario 1C

Scenario objectives :

- **Win** : Kill 2 investigators
- **Lose** : Investigators escape from Foyer

During my game session investigators revealed objective very quickly, and most of them managed to escape mansion before event was triggered and door's become locked with rune puzzle

Is this normal situation?

Comment: Are these experienced players that knew where to go?  Or just players that got lucky?

Comment: A bit of luck and a bit of experience i think. Joe Diamond and Ashane Pete with Duke make it very fast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a normal situation.  It isn't very fun, sure, but it is a normal one.  I've had it happen several times and each time I swear off playing this scenario until I find a new group of victi-- friends who have not yet experienced my wra-- version of fun.

In fact, I had a situation where one of my players simply wanted to "try and leave to see what happens".  Everyone else followed.  Game over in the first couple of turns.

Comment: FYI, from the FAQ, Investigators can only escape the map if the objective has been revealed and it allowed them to escape.

Comment: Confirmed that they can't escape till the objective is revealed.

Also, they're supposed to be hardened investigators, dedicated to rooting out evil, not munchkins attempting to game the system. If they try and pull this stuff on me, it's time for: "The door is sealed. You turn around. The Dead Have Risen. Take a horror test for each Zombie punching its way through the floor. Also, there is a Shoggoth. Take a horror test for the Shoggoth. Your turn ends due to your shock."

Answer (score 3):

The question here is how they revealed the objective so quickly. The main problem I've found with **Mansions of Madness** is that it doesn't give the Keeper enough info on how to run the game, which you have to figure out for yourself.

In the case of the first scenario, EVERYTHING should be geared to getting a maniac out and stealing samples as fast as possible, then **forcing investigators to chase him** rather than seeking the objective. The zombies can also be used in the same fashion, or be used as "blockers".

If the players *don't* stop the sample carrier, you can quickly build up enough threat that you can simply waylay them with Mythos cards.

One advantage you have is that by combining "Steal Sample" and "Command Minion", you can move 3 spaces on any turn where you start off sharing a space with an investigator, which allows you to outpace your foes and usually put a wall between yourself and any bullets, and that in the early turns you can gather Panic and Mythos without spending threat.

Combine this stuff with a continual pounding on their weaker stat (generally sanity for men, and health for women), and you can really slow them down.

Break a leg. No, literally, get them down to 4 health, and *break their leg*.